# Line passing through one point in software R

Tags: r, graphics, line

I'm new to [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)).

I'm trying to draw a square and a line through a point. This is the code I wrote...

```
plot(c(0, 2), c(0, 2), main="abc", type= "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
rect(0, 0, 1, 1, col=2) #square

m = runif(1, min=0, max=1) #angular coefficient
myLine <- function(x) m*(x-0.5)+0.5 # y = m*(x-0.5)+0.5 --> line through (0.5,0.5)

plot(myLine) #draw myLine
```

...but it doesn't work. Can you please explain to me what mistakes I made?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work" what exactly happens and what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: ok sorry. the rectangle isn't drawn and the line is always the same for every execution, even if the angular coefficient is random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `plot()`, R will usually create a brand new plot; it does not add it the existing plot by default. There are other functions such as `points()`, `lines()` and `curve()` that will draw on the existing plot.

Since you are tying to add a function, then you would need to use `curve()` to draw that function `myLine` you created. (If instead you wanted to randomly choose an intercept and slope, you could use the `abline()` function instead). But using your existing function, the code should look more like this

```
plot(c(0, 2), c(0, 2), main="abc", type= "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
rect(0, 0, 1, 1, col=2) #square

m <- runif(1, min=0, max=1) #angular coefficient
myLine <- function(x) m*(x-0.5)+0.5 # y = m*(x-0.5)+0.5 --> line through (0.5,0.5)

curve(myLine, add=TRUE) #draw myLine
```

which gives me this following plot

[image: square with random line]